# What is actually meant by "parallel paths" in a simplex progressive lap winding of a DC Generator?

Tags: dc-motor, generator, electric-machine

Many of my textbooks mention "parallel path" term, but I am unable to actually understand it. Also along with this it would be quite helpful to know, how the polarity of brushes is determined?
[image: simplex progressive lap winding]

Comment: A specific reference on some inspectable website that you can link is necessary. Do not assume we are about to guess which ref book you refer to or which page.

Answer (score 3):

Since the ends of each winding are bend inwards ( the beginning of a winding is placed at one lamella and the end of the same winding is placed at the next adjacent lamella this type of winding is called lap winding.
If you follow the windings you will find two parallel branches of windings for a 2 pole dc generator. For a four pole generator you will find 4 parallel branches of windings. From brush to brush you can consider each winding as a dc source and they are all in series so you will find Brush (lamella)- winding- lammela - winding -lammela - winding - brusch (lamella). This in two paths for a 2 pole machine and 4 paths for a 4 pole machine and so on.
Explanation of a wave winding and more in depth information you can find in
http://www.electrical4u.com/armature-winding-pole-pitch-coil-span-commutator-pitch/